# SQLite sub-query not working

Tags: android, sql, select, sqlite, scheduling

Table Name: `MRM_BOOKING_DETAILS`
Sample Data:

```
Booking_id USER_ID ROOM_ID CHECKIN             CHECKOUT
1          hary    1       2012-04-16 09:00:00 2012-04-16 09:30:00
2          jenny   2       2012-04-17 13:00:00 2012-04-17 13:30:00
3          steve   1       2012-04-16 15:00:00 2012-04-16 15:30:00
```

and so on...

`Booking_id` is the Primary Key. `Room_Id` is the Foreign Key w.r.t. the `Room_Details_Table` having `Room_Id` as PK.

My target is to get the list of records available on a particular day, particular time entered by the user. For doing this i came up with this query:

```
SELECT ROOMNO,BUILDINGNO 
FROM MRM_ROOM_DETAILS 
WHERE ROOMID IN (SELECT distinct roomid 
                FROM MRM_BOOKING_DETAILS 
                WHERE (CHECKIN NOT BETWEEN '2012-04-13 09:50:00' AND '2012-04-13 10:20:00')
                  and (CHECKOUT NOT BETWEEN '2012-04-13 09:50:00' AND '2012-04-13 10:20:00'))
  AND CAPACITY > 15 AND PROJECTIONSTATUS = 'NO';
```

`Capacity` and `ProjectionStatus` are columns in Room details table, please ignore that part as of now.

`CHECKIN` and `CHECKOUT` are the values provided by the user in search screen.

But unfortunately the sub-query is not correct, hence I am not getting the desired results.

```
SELECT distinct roomid 
FROM MRM_BOOKING_DETAILS 
WHERE (CHECKIN NOT BETWEEN '2012-04-13 09:50:00' AND '2012-04-13 10:20:00') and
      (CHECKOUT NOT BETWEEN '2012-04-13 09:50:00' AND '2012-04-13 10:20:00');
```

Here's why I say the sub-query is not correct. Suppose the values provided by the user are:

```
CHECKIN : 2012-04-16 09:00:00 and CHECKOUT: 2012-04-16 09:30:00
```

With the above data in the table, both `ROOM_ID` 1 and 2 will be returned. For the first row, it will fail, but it will succeed for the second and third row as a result it will return both 1 and 2 which is not correct. The correct result should be only 2.

Please help me to get the correct query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your logic from "rooms that are booked at times other than x" to "rooms that are not booked at x time."

Also, you should probably use the `DATETIME` function.

**UPDATE**

I've added checking for all intersections, and am not using the inclusive `BETWEEN` so that a room may be booked from 8:30 to 9:00 and from 9:00 to 9:30.

```
SELECT ROOMNO, BUILDINGNO 
FROM MRM_ROOM_DETAILS 
WHERE ROOMID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ROOM_ID as ROOMID
    FROM MRM_BOOKING_DETAILS 
    WHERE (DATETIME(CHECKIN) > DATETIME('2012-04-16 08:30:00') AND DATETIME(CHECKIN) < DATETIME('2012-04-16 09:31:00'))
        OR (DATETIME(CHECKOUT) > DATETIME('2012-04-16 08:30:00') AND DATETIME(CHECKOUT) < DATETIME('2012-04-16 09:31:00'))
        OR (DATETIME('2012-04-16 08:30:00') > DATETIME(CHECKIN) AND DATETIME('2012-04-16 08:30:00') < DATETIME(CHECKOUT))
        OR (DATETIME('2012-04-16 09:31:00') > DATETIME(CHECKIN) AND DATETIME('2012-04-16 09:31:00') < DATETIME(CHECKOUT))
)
    AND CAPACITY > 15
    AND PROJECTIONSTATUS = 'NO';
```

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite doesn't support date comparisons when the dates are strings. For this to work you need to convert all database side dates to numbers.